# How is return statement different in pycharm and python interpreter?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, return, repr

When I run this code in pycharm, I called my object but repr doesn't return anything, and in my python interpreter it returns `TypeError: __repr__ returned non-string (type NoneType)`. Why is that?

```
class DictionnaireOrdonne:

    liste_clefs = []
    liste_valeurs = []

    def __init__(self, **clefs_valeurs):

        self.clefs_valeurs = clefs_valeurs
        self._dictionnaire = {}

    def __repr__(self):

        return self.clefs_valeurs

    def __getitem__(self, key):

        return self._dictionnaire[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):

        self._dictionnaire[key] = value


test = DictionnaireOrdonne(one=1, two=2)
test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enter an expression in the Python REPL, it evaluates the expression and tries to print out the `repr()` of the result.  `repr()` calls your object's `__repr__()`, checks that return value is a string and throws the error.

Outside the REPL (e.g. when you run it in PyCharm) the expression result is simply discarded, `repr()` is not called so no error is raised.

Comment: What exactly do you want to work in PyCharm? If you need to print the repr() of your object, call `print(repr(test))`

Comment: I need it to return my dict (in my example: {'one': 1, 'two': 2}) just like it does in the python interpreter by just calling my object test

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite clear what the issue is here. Your `__repr__` method is not returning a string, it is returning a dict.

Although not entirely explicit in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) you have to return a string from `__repr__`.

Why it is returning nothing in PyCharm instead of the error I can't tell you.

Comment: Thank you, I converted it into a str and it works, but that is only true for python interpreter, still doesn't return anything in Pycharm.

Comment: Sorry I don't use PyCharm so I can't help there